# Exception sending xml string to webservice C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I am calling a webservice method . The input parameter is a string xml format. All time is bouncing an exception because the service expects a string with xml format but this auto encoding as html How do I can prevent this change is made and the xml will send your < and > ?.

Exception: The content type text / html; charset = utf -8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding ( application / soap + xml; charset = utf -8).

Comment: You should show how you're calling the web service (manually? via a generated proxy? something else?), what you've observed in terms of the request (e.g. via Fiddler or Wireshark) and what the exception is.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to call the webservice, and the XML you're sending?

Comment: I used httpanalyzer (similar to fiddler) for shipping. That's where I saw that is performing the encoding of characters to html xml

Comment: I send a xml, the problem is that encode the < and > to & lt ; and & gt ;